# Is a entity class can return some other entity instance in OOAD?

Tags: java, oop, ooad

I have two classes:

```
public class Car
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String vendor;

    /* ... */
}

public class Garage 
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    /* get-set and others stuffs */

    public boolean addCar(Car c) {
        /*
            This will insert a car to tblCars
            but belong to this garage
        */
    }

    public List<Car> getListCar {
        /* 
            This will perform a SELECT query on tblCars
            to choose cars belong to this Garage
        */
    }
}
```

Is it allowed in OOAD?

Answer (score 1):

Allowed?  What do you think is going to happen - an OOAD cop pull you over to the side and give you a ticket?

You can do anything you want.  You'll find out if it's misguided after the fact.

Your design looks acceptable, except the Garage does not have a `Collection<Car>`.

This is a one-to-many relationship between `Car` and `Garage`.  That's how it's usually done.

I think the Smalltalk MVC ideas are a little outdated.  Here's how I see layers for a web app:

```
view-->controller-->service--+-->persistence
                             |
                             +--> model
```

Controller and view and tightly coupled together.

The service is the thing that knows about DAOs and model objects.  They fulfill use cases and own units of work.

Comment: Thanks, I mean, for example, in 3-tier design pattern, Presentation layer shouldn't make a direct call to Data Access Layer but throught a Control layer, so, are these any rules that prohibit one entity call/access/return to other entites?

Comment: view should have no reference to controller (in MVC). The arrow should be from controller to view.

Comment: It's intended to show info flow, not dependency

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your requirements.  If you are required to save a car every time it goes into a garage then use a delegate to handle the DB insert :

```
public boolean addCar(Car c) {
    Delegate.getInstance().addCarToGarage(this, c);
}

public List<Car> getListCar {
    Delegate.getInstance().getAllCars();
}
```

Otherwise just leave it as

```
public boolean addCar(Car c) {
    myCarList.add(c);
}

public List<Car> getListCar {
    return myCarList();
}
```

And save it at some other point.